# Dependency injection error when receiving message with @ServiceActivator

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration

It even goes into my AnotherService, but all the other Autowired objects inside AnotherService don't seem to have injected.

`@Transactional` was an attempt, I also added `@EnableIntegration` and `@EnableTransactionManagement`, but without success.

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Component
public class ReceiverMessageService {

    @Autowired
    private AnotherService anotherService;

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "MyInputChannel")
    @Transactional
    public void messageReceiver(byte[] payload) {
        // work with payload ...
        this.anotherService.doAnything(/*myPayload*/);
    }
}
```

When I evaluate the autowired objects inside AnotherService I get this:

```
CGLIB$BOUND = false
CGLIB$CALLBACK_0 = {CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor@19413} 
CGLIB$CALLBACK_1 = {CglibAopProxy$StaticUnadvisedInterceptor@19414} 
...
...
...
...
```

This is the error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no attributes found in the request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: no attributes found in the request
```

Comment: The question is not clear. Please , be more specific : what is an expectation and what exactly the problem

Comment: When I get a message through this @ServiceActivator my injected objects seem to have no context. I even managed to initialize them manually with this trick, but it is impractical.
Using this method I query the bd.


`B bean = new B();
AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
factory.autowireBean( bean );
factory.initializeBean( bean, "bean" );`

Comment: I’m sorry what is context? What is `AnotherService`? Can you share more stack trace?

Comment: `No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request

So, you have a problem with an HTTP request entity outside of the HTTP thread. See if you can transfer that info via method call param instead of injection attempt of the resource which is not available in that thread any more. Or make sure you don’t change threads after receiving HTTP request.